# git remote directory path rewrite

Tags: git

I have created a git user on my server, who's home directory is in `/home/git`. I've added my `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` file so I don't have to authenticate using a password. My repositories live in `/opt/git`. So I can access my repositories with:

`git@<hostname>:/opt/git/<reponame>`

My problem is that I would like to be able to access my repositories like:

`git@<hostname>:<reponame>`

As a horribly hackish fix I created symlinks from all the repositories in `/opt/git` to `/home/git`. I don't want the repositories to live in the git users home directory because other processes on the system running as different users need access to the repositories.

How can I configure my server to access `/opt/git` automatically when receiving changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the git users home directory to `/opt/git` which would do the same thing as symlinking the git repos did.

Comment: Can't do that because the `/opt/git` directory has to have permissions set to 775. As far as I'm aware public/private key auth requires that the home directory be secured to 700.

Comment: No, only the .ssh folder has to be set to 700.

Comment: Heh, just tried that out. You're right. Now say I wanted to have my `/home` mounted to one partition and my `/opt` mounted to another. Guess I'd just like to keep it clean and have all my `.bash*` and `.vim*` stay in home and have all the repos linked elsewhere. If it's not possible, that's cool. Just looking for a more optimal solution.

Comment: That isn't possible. However you should have those files under the git user in the first place, or they are not necessary.